# query to join two tables using a primary key and comma separate the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there are two tables-

```
T1                  T2
---             ----------
A                A  |   1
A                A  |   2
A                A  |   3
```

How to write a query that returns the results as following

```
Col1    Col2
----    -----
  A     1,2,3
```

(One row)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you rephrase? Can't make out what the data in the tables are.

Comment: your question is not understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @tempA Table
(Val Char(1))

DECLARE @tempB Table
(Val Char(1),
 ID INT)

 INSERT INTO @tempA
 SELECT 'A'
 UNION 
 SELECT 'A'
 UNION 
 SELECT 'A'

 INSERT INTO @tempB
 SELECT 'A',1
 UNION 
 SELECT 'A',2
 UNION 
 SELECT 'A',3


 SELECT DISTINCT Val,STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ID)as 'data()'
              FROM @tempB B
              Where B.Val = A.Val
              FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'')
FROM @tempA A
```

Hope this will solve.